# Guaranteed rewriting file, keeping old copy if process fails?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best way of guaranteed rewriting old file withe new one, I need to detect if this operation has failed and use last known version of the valid file?

In my code I am writing to the `.temp` file as this can be over 100MB, deleting original file, and renaming temp to the original file. There are as well recovery steps.

I am worried for `File.Move` operation as I don't know what steps are happening?

```
File.Move(_fullTempPath, _fullPath); 


public class JsonFileCache
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private string _fileName;

    private string _fullPath
    {
       get { return _path + _fileName; }
    }

    private string _fullTempPath
    {
        get { return _path + _fileName + ".temp"; }
    }

    public JsonFileCache(string fileName, string cacheDirectory)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
        _path = cacheDirectory;
    }

    public T GetOrCreate<T>() where T : new()
    {
        CreateDirectoryIfDoesNotExists(_path);

        if (File.Exists(_fullTempPath) && !File.Exists(_fullPath))
        {
            File.Move(_fullTempPath, _fullPath);
        }

        if (!File.Exists(_fullPath))
        {
            File.Create(_fullPath);
            return new T();
        }

        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(_fullPath);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
        {
            return new T();
        }

        var data = jsonString.FromJson<T>();

        return data;
    }

    private void CreateDirectoryIfDoesNotExists(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    public void Save<T>(T data)
    {
        CreateDirectoryIfDoesNotExists(_path);
        var jsonString = data.ToJson();
        File.WriteAllText(_fullTempPath, jsonString);
        File.Delete(_fullPath);
        File.Move(_fullTempPath, _fullPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: write with temp name, if succeeds delete old, and rename new

Comment: I think try/catch is what you're looking for, surrond your write/delete/move actions with it. If something go wrong, you'll get an exception.

Comment: what if machine crashes, there might not be exception, or this is running in the IIS and app pool is recycled, I have checked events, File.Move does not create any new files temp dir ..... if source dest is the same id is windows rename command

Comment: what if you stop reinventing wheel and use existing system that supports versioning (any source control system) or transactions (like traditional DBs - i.e. MSSQL)?

Comment: Because name of the class is JsonFileCache, not DB, it need to be really fast, sending 5x100MB every 10s will take some time.
Esent Persistent Dictionary is another option but it requires more changes on existing code to use it, file cache is the quickest implementation and it works really fast
http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation